# Find the length of a filter object in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I find the length of a filter object in python 3?

```
def is_valid_file(filename):
  return True

full_path_fnames = filter(is_valid_file, full_path_fnames)

print(len(full_path_fnames))
```

Answer (score 12):

You can say how much elements did it have only after you finish iterating over it. Built-in [`len`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html?highlight=filter#len) function calls [`__len__` method](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__len__#object.__len__) of an object and, as you can see, `filter` objects don't have that method

```
>>> '__len__' in dir(filter(bool, [0, 1, 2]))
False
```

because they're basically iterators.

One possible way to find the length is

```
>>> sum(1 for _ in filter(bool, [0, 1, 2]))
2
```

Another one is to convert it to `list` type, which of course has length:

```
>>> len(list(filter(bool, [0, 1, 2])))
2
```

Note, that all solutions will exhaust the iterator, so you won't be able to reuse it:

```
>>> f = filter(bool, [0, 1, 2])
>>> list(f) 
[1, 2]
>>> list(f) 
[]
```

Comment: `sum(1 for _ in filter(func, iterable))` is the preferred way if you can't fit the entire iterable in memory.

Answer (score 3):

In Python2.x, `filter` is returning a `list`, but in Python3 it is giving you an iterator which you can convert to a `list` and then check the length:

```
len(list(filter(foo, bar)))
```

Demo:

```
>>> filter(lambda x: x < 3, [1,2,3])
<filter object at 0x7fdf9ea1af90>
>>> list(filter(lambda x: x < 3, [1,2,3]))
[1, 2]
>>> len(list(filter(lambda x: x < 3, [1,2,3])))
2
```