# TypeError: object of type 'filter' has no len()

Tags: python, arrays, list

When executing my Python script, I'm receiving the following error...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/jira-cycle-extract", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jira_cycle_extract/cli.py", line 144, in main
    cycle_data = q.cycle_data(verbose=args.verbose)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jira_cycle_extract/cycletime.py", line 141, in cycle_data
for snapshot in self.iter_changes(issue, False):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jira_cycle_extract/query.py", line 114, in iter_changes
last_status = status_changes[0].fromString if len(status_changes) != 0 else issue.fields.status.name
TypeError: object of type 'filter' has no len()
```

I've tried to address this by adding the following code based on other research, and changing from `> 0` to `not empty` or other forms to check for an empty list, but had no luck.

This is the code in question...

```
status_changes = filter(
        lambda h: h.field == 'status',
        itertools.chain.from_iterable([c.items for c in issue.changelog.histories])
    )

last_status = status_changes[0].fromString if len(status_changes) != 0 else issue.fields.status.name
    last_resolution = None
```

Comment: The package you're attempting to use does not support Python 3.

Comment: @user2357112 These 2 links can help you: 1> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939960/python-filter-max-combo-checking-for-empty-iterator   2> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24291604/find-the-length-of-a-filter-object-in-python-3/24291630#24291630  . Converting it to list or iterating would however exhaust the filter, so checking if its empty is the approach you should take in my opinion.

Comment: Try `status_changes=list(filter ...)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `next` function with a generator expression and a default value instead. The code in your question can be re-written as:

```
last_status = next((h.fromString for c in issue.changelog.histories for h in c.items if h.field == 'status'), issue.fields.status.name)
last_resolution = None
```

Answer (score 0):

- Error: `TypeError: object of type 'filter' has no len()`
- Reason:

  - `Python 2`: `filter()` return **list**
  - `Python 3`: `filter()` return **Object** of type `filter`
- Solution: change `filter(xxx)` to `list(filter(xxx))`

  - for yours

    - change from

      ```py
      status_changes = filter(
              lambda h: h.field == 'status',
              itertools.chain.from_iterable([c.items for c in issue.changelog.histories])
          )
      ```
    - to

      ```py
      status_changes = list(filter(
              lambda h: h.field == 'status',
              itertools.chain.from_iterable([c.items for c in issue.changelog.histories])
          ))
      ```